# Set observe business closures on the user weekly calendar calendar via plugin

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I'm facing a problem with the creation of user calendar via plugin. So, could I set the option "Observe" on the 'Business Closures' weekly calendar field via C# plugin?

I am already able to create the calendar and set all other options, but for some reason, this 'Business Closures' field does not exist in the Calendarrules entity metadata, as a consequence I can not set it

Has anyone managed to do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: This article might help: https://community.dynamics.com/365/projectserviceautomation/f/767/t/294030

Comment: Hi Aron, 

it's a good debate, but they are mention the client-side approach, I'm actually trying to do the same but using the server-side way via C# plugin 

At that point, I can not find anything related  =(